# CSS Font displaying fine in Chrome but not FF or IE

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fonts

I have created a landing page and needed a headline to be Avenir font. I got this to render properly in Chrome, but it does not work for any other browser. Is there something that I am missing?

## CSS

```
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5, .section h2 {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        color:#c41230;
        font-family: AvenirLT-Black;
        font-weight:normal;
    }
```

## HTML

```
<div class="ten columns title">
          <h1 style="font:AvenirLT-Black">Additional Information</h1>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `font-family` value is passed on through to the OS font subsystem.

Windows has two different font subsystems: DirectWrite and GDI.  Chrome uses the older GDI; Firefox and IE use DirectWrite.

GDI doesn't have a way to represent more than two different font weights per family, so fonts that are extra-bold or extra-light get mapped to different family names, typically suffixed with "Black" or "Light" or "ExtraLight".  DirectWrite, on the other hand, can represent multiple weights per family.  So chances are DirectWrite is seeing your font as a font with the family name "AvenirLT" and an extra-bold font weight.  So you want to do something like this:

```
font-family: AvenirLT, AvenirLT-Black;
font-weight: 900;
```

Comment: I'm sure I left out other css pieces that affected this. I appreciate the help, below is a link to the page. It is not my code, I was just trying to help out a friend. The h3 text in the gray bar seems to work fine so I'm not sure what the issue is:

http://content.czarnowski.com/acton/fs/blocks/showLandingPage/a/5795/p/p-0031/t/page/fm/0

Comment: @Fathon Did you try changing the styles to what I suggested?

Comment: I did Still not seeming to work:

http://content.czarnowski.com/acton/fs/blocks/showLandingPage/a/5795/p/p-0031/t/page/fm/0

Comment: You didn't change the `font-weight` value, right?  That part is sort of important.

Comment: I have now done that. I can get it to work in different browsers at different times but not all at once. There is css font code in several places and I'm not sure what the issue is. Here are a few:

`h1 {
   font-size:45px;
   line-height:48px;
   margin-bottom:20px;
   font-family: AvenirLT, AvenirLT-Black;
   font-weight: 900;`


`.pagetitle h1, .homecaption h2, #logo h1 a, #logo h2 a {
  font-family: AvenirLT, AvenirLT-Black; font-weight: 900; letter-spacing: -.02em; text-transform:none;}`

Comment: Working in IE and FF but not Chrome now. Still the same link:http://content.czarnowski.com/acton/fs/blocks/showLandingPage/a/5795/p/p-0031/t/page/fm/0

Comment: Ah, what about if you do `font-family: AvenirLT-Black, AvenirLT`?  Chrome might be finding the normal AvenirLT font and using it...